# Using CSS grids in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, css, css-grid

So, I built a website and now I'm turning it into a customizable wordpress theme. 
The thing is: I used CSS grid to build a gallery, and I want to make it dynamic. I need to upload the photos (and sometimes videos or gifs) in wordpress and have them fit in the grid.

This is my code:

```
**HTML**
 <div class="gallery">
        <figure class="figure1">
            <img src="img/r1.jpg" class="figure-img">
        </figure>

        <figure class="figure2">
            <img src="img/r2.jpg" class="figure-img">
        </figure>

        <figure class="figure3">
            <img src="img/r3.jpg" class="figure-img">
        </figure>

        <figure class="figure4">
            <img src="img/r4.jpg" class="figure-img">
        </figure>

        <!-- more figures -->
</div>


 **CSS**
 .gallery {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
 }

 .figure-img {
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     object-fit: cover;
     margin-bottom: 0
 }

 .figure1 {
     grid-column: span 1;
 }

 .figure2 {
     grid-column: span 3;
 }

 .figure3 {
    grid-column: span 4;
 }

 .figure4 {
     grid-column: span 4;
 }

 /* more figures */
```

Since some of the images are not supposed to occupy the entire row and others are (it's a bit random), I can't just use a regular gallery plugin.

I must add I'm a beginner when it comes to php...
Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using Advanced Custom Fields Pro? You can use the repeater field and create the gallery and create custom classes to toggle each image for grid size.

Comment: I have and it would be a good idea, but I want to try to build it myself so I don't have to depend on a plugin...